# \renewcommand not executed for \div

Tags: unicode-math

In the following code the math text for \div is wrong:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\renewcommand{\i}{\symup{i}}  
\newcommand{\const}{\symup{const}}  
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}

\renewcommand{\div}{\symup{div}\,}
\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}
    \rot \vec{a} + \grad \vec{a} + \div \vec{a} + \rect f(x) + \e^{-\i x} = \const
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

The `\div` is not changed by the `\renewcommand`
[image]

Comment: move it behind \begin{document}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the \div is already definited and and you cannot have two distinct outputs for the same command \div.

Comment: Why not simply denote your `div` by `\curl`? (E.g., `\DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{div}`)?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Div and curl are different things. Do you think of curl vs rot?

Comment: @Sebastiano I know, but I assume that Matthias simply wants the new definition, and as unicode-math does lots of setup at begin document, that means that his definition should come later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @mickep Oh, sorry. Curl, indeed! It was the actual case when in the Polish version there was rot, and changing it into the curl for the English version was a one-minute work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You need to delay the redefinition at begin document, because `unicode-math` needs to do its setup there, when all fonts are surely known.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\renewcommand{\i}{\symup{i}}  
\newcommand{\const}{\symup{const}}  
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{equation}
    \rot \vec{a} + \grad \vec{a} + \div \vec{a} + \rect f(x) + \e^{-\i x} = \const
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm *certain* that “i” and “e” should not be upright (at least in many people's document, including mine), but this is a matter of opinion. However, I can't understand why the different treatment.

Beware that both `\symup{div}\,` and the also proposed

```
\ensuremath{\text{div}}
```

are wrong. Your `\symup{div}` does not behave as the math operator it should be. Miyase's `\text{div}` would make eyebrows to raise if it appears in the statement of a theorem (and the spacing around it is completely wrong).

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do exactly the same thing, and struggled with some packages that redefined `\div`. Here's what I ended up doing, and it's been working flawlessly so far:

```
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\let\div\relax\newcommand{\div}{\ensuremath{\text{div}}}}
```

It's in my preamble.

The use of `\text` might not be the best choice, but that's a different (and minor) problem.

Comment: Why `\ensuremath`? But that's the least problem. Your `\div` doesn't behave as an operator like `\log` and similar with regard to spacing around it. Moreover, try to use it in the statement of a theorem and you'll have a surprise.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the comment, I'll have a look at it. I use `\ensuremath` out of habit for all macros that are math mode-only. As for its use in a theorem-like environment, I never use those. If I remember correctly, when I tried to (re)define `\div` as an operator, I ran into conflicts with packages that seemed to alter this macro late in the preamble. Nevertheless, I'll try the answer you posted.

Answer (score 2):

I have put `\divg` command instead of `\div` that is a predefinite command for the division symbol.

```
  \DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{\symup{div}\,}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\renewcommand{\i}{\symup{i}}  
\newcommand{\const}{\symup{const}}  
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}
\DeclareMathOperator{\divg}{\symup{div}\,}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}
    \rot \vec{a} + \grad \vec{a} + \divg  \vec{a} + \rect f(x) + \e^{-\i x} = \const 
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```